# Change color in qtablewidget (click on)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Help implement the code so that when you click on a cell in the table, the widget cell changes its color, and when you click it again, it turns white again

I'm trying to implement the filemanager.

Code:

```
def onClicked(self, cell):
   if not self.highlight_mode:
        print(cell)
        if cell.text() == '..':
            self.path = str(Path(self.path).parent)
            print(self.path)
        else:
            if not os.path.isfile(self.path + "\\" + str(cell.text())):
                self.path = self.path + "\\" + str(cell.text())

        print(self.path)
        try:
            os.chdir(self.path)
            self.list_dir = os.listdir(self.path)
            self.list_dir.insert(0, '..')
        except:
            buttonReply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'ERROR', "ERROR",
                                               QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.Ok)
        self.update_table()            
    else:
        if cell.text() != '..':
            self.list_with_select.append(self.path + '\\' + str(cell.text()))
            print(self.list_with_select)


def update_table(self):
    self.tableWidget.clear()
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(self.list_dir))
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(1)
    count = 0
    for nel in self.list_dir:
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, count, QTableWidgetItem(nel))
        count += 1


def cut(self):
    for i in self.list_with_select:
        shutil.move(i, self.path + '\\')
    self.list_with_select.clear()           

def highlight_m(self):
    print('recup')
    if not(self.highlight_mode):
        self.highlight_mode = True
    else:
        self.highlight_mode = False
    print(self.highlight_mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must toggle the QBrush associated with the Qt::BackgroundRole function of each element. You can use itemClicked but this may fail because not all items in QTableWidget have an associated QTableWidgetItem, so it is better to use the clicked signal returned by the associated QModelIndex

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tableWidget)

        self.tableWidget.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(10)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    def on_clicked(self, ix):
        alternative_color = QtGui.QColor("salmon")

        current_brush = ix.data(QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole)
        new_brush = (
            QtGui.QBrush(alternative_color)
            if current_brush in (None, QtGui.QBrush())
            else QtGui.QBrush()
        )

        self.tableWidget.model().setData(ix, new_brush, QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```